# How to get AppData/LocalLow path in C++?

Tags: c++

Using this code below I could get the Roaming file path but how do I get the LocalLow file path.

```
char* appdata = getenv("APPDATA");
    printf("Appdata: %s\n",appdata);

//this returns the ff: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming
```

How do I get it to return C:\Users\Username\AppData\LocalLow

Comment: `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow)`

Comment: `[Error] too few arguments to function 'HRESULT SHGetKnownFolderPath(const KNOWNFOLDERID&, DWORD, HANDLE, WCHAR**)'` I get this error

Comment: You could [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) to determine what other arguments you need to provide.

Comment: I have no Idea how the third and fourth argument works.

Comment: `PWSTR path = nullptr; SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow, 0, 0, &path);` When done with `path`, call `CoTaskMemFree(path)` to free the memory that `SHGetKnownFolderPath` has allocated.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this information should be posted as an answer instead of in comments.